# What is the difference between tensorflow saved_model.pb and frozen_inference_graph.pb?

Tags: tensorflow, training, object-detection

I've re-trained a model (following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-a-tensorflow-face-object-detection-model-3599dcd0c26f)) from the [google's object detection zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) (ssd_inception_v2_coco) on a WIDER Faces Dataset and it seems to work if I use `frozen_inference_graph.pb` from python, but if i take `saved_model.pb` and put it to tensorflow serving, it predicts a lot of detections all with confidence less than 0.10.

Another thing that I do not understand is that both files are 52Mb however the original files downloaded from the object detection zoo take 98Mb each.

Here's an example of predictions made with the `saved_model` and tensorflow serving:

[image: Predictions by TensorFlow Serving]

And here's example of predictions by the same model, but using `frozen_inference_graph.pb`:

[image: Predictions by python code and frozen_inference_graph.pb]

1. So what is the actual difference between the `saved_model.pb` and the `frozen_inference_graph.pb`?
2. Are there any ways to inspect what's wrong with the `saved_model.pb` i use?
3. How the much smaller size of the re-trained model vs the original could be explained?

Answer (score 4):

**saved_model.pb** may represent multiple graph definitions as MetaGraphDef protocol buffers. Weights and other variables usually aren't stored inside the file during training. Instead, they're held in separate checkpoint files

---

[image: Tensorflow Saved Model].

---

**frozen_inference_graph.pb** has its variables converted into inline constants so everything’s in one file and ready for serving on any platform including mobile. Freezing process includes loading the GraphDef, pull in the values for all the variables from the latest checkpoint file, and then replace each Variable op with a Const that has the numerical data for the weights stored in its attributes It then strips away all the extraneous nodes that aren't used for forward inference. Reference: [Tensorflow Model Files](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/model_files)